# Injection in Injected class with Jersey

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I am having problems understanding injection principles in Java (im originally coming frm .NET world).

I have class extending frm AbstractBinder that contains two bindings:

```
bind(new Class1()).to(Class1Interface.class);
bind(Class2.class).to(Class2Interface.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

In Class2 i have:

```
@Inject
Class1Interface Instance;
```

Instance value is always null... What do i do wrong?

**ADD0:**
I assume there might be some configuration issue. Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.myapp.configuration.AppMain</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**ADD1: Class1 and Class2**

```
public interface Class1Interface{
Properties getProperties();
}

public Class1 extends Class1Interface{
@Override
public getProperties(){...}
}

public interface Class2Interface{
void SomeMethod();
}

public class Class2 extends Class2Interface{

@Inject
Class1Interface Config;

@Override
public void SomeMethod(){...}
}
```

Binder details listed earlier in the question.

Comment: Does not look to be. Even with bind(Class1).to(Class1)l bind(Class2).to(Class2); it does not work. Value is null when coming to Class2 constructor. Its interesting values for both of them are set when i get into Controller method.

Comment: Not enough info. 1) Are you registering the binder? 2) Where/how are you trying to get the instance of Class2? Can you show both.

Comment: Also can you show the Class1 and Class2

Comment: @peeskillet: 1. sure i have my binder registered from `class AppMain extends ResourceConfig` as follows: `register(new MyBinder());` and its successfully run before i try to access Class1 inside Class2. 2. As ive written in the description, i try to access Class1 value inside Class2. See details in question.

Comment: How are you trying to access Class2. Please show that also

Comment: Ok, i guess thanks to ur guideance @peeskillet ive got an answer. In Class2 i was tryin to access Class1Interface value in Class2.Constructor and therefore it was null. In .NET i would specify Class1Interface as constructor parameter for Class2. Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Your code you posted doesn't reflect that. Please next time you post a question, make sure the code reproduces the problem. As for your question, Yes you can, but you need to add `@Inject` annotation on top/before the constructor, and remove the no-arg constructor